# Seeding Math::Random::ISAAC from /dev/urandom : How to read/pass 128 bits?

Tags: perl, file, unix, random, binary

There are many ways to create secure random numbers in Perl. Most of these ways involve one or more Perl modules. Many of these Perl modules require even more Perl modules as dependencies.

Since I want to keep things very light-weight and reduce dependencies required, I decided to use `Math::Random::ISAAC`, and to seed it myself from `/dev/urandom`.

So, what would be the recommended way to read, say 128 bits (I guess that is a good amount) of data from `/dev/urandom`, in Perl, without using another module, and then to pass it to `ISAAC`?

I don't know what the right way of reading and formatting would be, here is a copy of [the sub I will be passing the seed to:](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JAWNSY/Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004/lib/Math/Random/ISAAC/PP.pm)

```
sub new {
  my ($class, @seed) = @_;

  my $seedsize = scalar(@seed);

  my @mm;
  $#mm = $#seed = 255; # predeclare arrays with 256 slots

  # Zero-fill our seed data
  for ($seedsize .. 255) {
    $seed[$_] = 0;
  }

  my $self = {
    randrsl   => \@seed,
    randcnt   => 0,
    randmem   => \@mm,

    randa     => 0,
    randb     => 0,
    randc     => 0,
  };

  bless($self, $class);

  $self->_randinit();

  return $self;
}
```

I am not an expert in the specifics of arrays, scalars, byte strings, etc; so I don't really know how to format the `urandom` data into `@seed` appropriately. I do think that 128 bits is plenty of randomness, but I do not know how to make sure that all that entropy makes it into `ISAAC`, and to prevent it from being truncated to 64 or 32 bits along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the ISAAC code that uses the seed, it appears to want 32 bit values.  So:

```
use autodie;
open(my $fh,'<','/dev/urandom');
my $buffer;
read($fh, $buffer, 16) == 16 or die "not enough read";
my @seed = unpack 'L4', $buffer;
my $isaac = Math::Random::ISAAC->new(@seed);
```